# Access applications folder without jailbreak

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, sandbox, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to access the applications folder which allows a read access without jailbreak but i'm getting a null array

```
NSArray *appFolderContents=[[NSFileManager defaultManager] 
                            directoryContentsAtPath:@"/var/mobile/Applications"];
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have access to your app directory like this

```
   NSString *appFolderPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
   NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];  
   NSLog(@"App Directory is: %@", appFolderPath);
   NSLog(@"Directory Contents:\n%@", [fileManager directoryContentsAtPath: appFolderPath]);
```

Note you have read only right in the root folder, and write and read in `Documents` folder of your app.

You have no access for any folder outside your app bundle.

Comment: I want to get other applications directories, How apps like iFunbox able to get access to applications folder ?

Comment: What folder exactly `iFunbox` has access to? Only thing I could see is the access to photos folder. Is this what you want?

Comment: In iFunbox I can see "User Applications" which contains a list of installed apps.

Comment: this iFunbox doesn't  seem to have list of apps: https://itunes.apple.com/ch/app/ifunbox/id785964044?mt=8